# Como obter a chave de uma keygen?

Tags: javascript

Possuo um documento HTML com um formulário e quero através dele enviar uma chave aleatória para o servidor. Para fazer isso, estou utilizando o elemento `<keygen>`.

Antes que os dados sejam enviados, eu preciso obter o valor desse elemento `<keygen>` para armazenar localmente a chave gerada. Tentei o seguinte código:

```js
function getKey() {
    const keygen = document.getElementsByTagName("keygen")[0];
    sessionStorage.token = keygen.accessKey;
}

document.onsubmit = getKey;
```

O problema é que ele devolve sempre uma string vazia ao invés da chave gerada. O que eu devo fazer para obter a chave antes do envio do formulário?

Comment: [`<keygen>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen) é um recurso obsoleto do HTML5. Eu questionaria o seu uso.

Comment: Só quero deixar claro que não fui eu quem dei o negativo na pergunta. Apesar de ser um elemento obsoleto, não acho que a pergunta seja ruim... Até gostaria de saber o porquê do negativo.

Comment: Votei na pergunta também não vejo a necessidade do negativo.

Comment: O atributo que você estava procurando é `challenge` mas sinto muito informar que a tag `<keygen>` não funciona mais em nenhum navegador a API foi removida: Referência https://caniuse.com/#search=keygen

Comment: Então o que eu deveria usar para gerar chaves aleatórias ? Não quero criar uma função inteira só pra isso ;/

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 isso ajuda [`Window.crypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) ?

Comment: Usar <keygen> te retornará [object HTMLUnknownElement] em localStorage ou sessionStorage.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, acho que vale **[edit]** a pergunta para dizer o que você realmente precisa fazer. Se você quer gerar chaves aleatórias, `<keygen>` — tag depreciada —, não me parece ser um requisito, certo?